# Create a tag synonym

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

Request that a synonym/merge be created for infopath -> infopath2010

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infopath2010

Comment: AAAH! Version tagging Meta question! AAAH! *runs back to Main*

Comment: fyi you can use tags in text: [tag:infopath]

Answer (score 1):

@Anders created the synonym.. I think he just forgot to post here after doing it. :)